# Reduction Formulae of $I_n=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^nx\, dx$ and $J_n=(-1)^nI_{2n}$

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations, integral-inequality

Let $I_n=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\tan^nx\,dx$ and let $J_n=(-1)^nI_{2n}$ for $n=0,1,2$

1. Show that $I_n+I_{n+2}=\frac{1}{n+1}$.
2. Deduce that $J_n-J_{n-1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}$ for $n\ge1$
3. Show that $J_m=\frac{\pi}4+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}$.
4. Use the substitution $u=\tan x$ to show that $I_n=\int_0^1\frac{u^n}{1+u^2}du$.
5. Deduce that $0 \le I_n \le \frac{1}{n+1}$ and conclude that $J_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

This is for the Proofs topic of the Extension 2 HSC maths course. This belongs to a section using recurrence integrals, but I think there is a bit of inequalities proof at the end.

I have attempted the first section. I could proof that $I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac1{n-1}$ by splitting $\tan^nx$ into $\tan^{n-2}x \cdot \tan^2x$. I can see that it is in some ways similar, but I can't quite get it.

I have successfully done part four:

> $I_n=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}4}\tan^nx\,dx$
>
> $u=\tan x$; $\frac{du}{dx}=\sec^2x$
>
> $I_n=\int_0^1u^n\frac{dx}{\sec^2x}=\int_0^1\frac{u^n}{1+u^2}du$

I know this is a really long question, but I really don't understand how to do it. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: Probably, there is a typo in 3.

Comment: @Bumblebee Yes there is! Thank you!

Comment: Also for 1. use your starting point with the fact that $\tan^2x=\sec^2x-1$ and use a substitution to integrate $\tan^{n-2}x\sec^2x.$

Comment: @Bumblebee I did that. But it got me to $I_n+I_{n-2}=\frac1{n-1}$, not what the question was asking for.

Comment: You already have what you want. Replace $n$ by $n+2$ here $\uparrow$

Comment: Start from $(4)$, you should prove the statements in following orders $$\begin{array}{c}(4) &\implies& (1)& \implies &(2)&\implies&(3)\\
& &\Downarrow\\ & & (5)\end{array}$$

Comment: Observe that
$$
\left(\tan x\right)'=1+\tan^2x,\qquad x \in \left[0,\frac \pi4\right]
$$giving for $n=0,1,2,\cdots$,
$$
I_n+I_{n+2}=\int_0^{\large \frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^nx \left(1+\tan^2x \right) \,dx=\int_0^{1}u^n \,du=\frac 1{n+1}.$$

Comment: @achillehui can you explain how to get (5)?

Comment: @JieshunWang Both $I_n, I_{n+1}$ are integrals with non-negative integrands, so they are non-negative. This implies $I_n = \frac{1}{n+1} - I_{n+1} \le \frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: @achillehui could you elaborate on why if the integrands are non-negative, then the integral itself is non-negative?